# Spring: is there built in way to raise jsr303 validation exception in service layer?

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have a model with jsr 303 annotations and service

```
public class User {
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2)
    private String username;

    @NotNull 
    private String email;

    ... 
}

@Component
public class UserServiceImpl extends UserService {

     public void createNewUser(@Valid User user) {
         ...
     } 
}
```

Is there any build-in way to raise validation exceptions (if any) whenever I call method on this service , like in Controller layer?

```
...
userService->createNewUser(user) <- Here I want validation exceptions to be thrown
...
```

P.S: I can do it with spring AOP, but I wonder if there is build in way.

Comment: Not sure, but you are violating the concern of the service layer, and introducing exceptions deeper into your code base than they need to be.

Comment: I put validation (also security) in service layer, science I have two interfaces which interacts with my application: rest and sockets, and I don't want to duplicate validation and security code. What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: I will write answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in Spring the validation is integrated with your controller, so that validation messages get propagated back to the view, and you see something like for example: invalid email next to an email text box. The other place validation is used is in persistence, when you have constraints for when you are going to commit, update and delete. You cannot do these actions if the corresponding validation constraint is violated.

So it's clear a controller will show the error in your view, and a DAO won't commit to your database when validation fails. Now what do you expect to happen in the service layer? I can only think of that you would want to throw an exception if you call a method with the incorrect arguments. I guess you could make a case like you have for using aspect orientated programming to throw exceptions when this happens as you already know.

But I don't think anyone finds it too useful to have parameter validation at this level because you can't automatically display it back on the view like you can when you have validation in your request parameters in a controller. It would be better to find these violations in the controller so that the user can see these back in the view.

If you do choose to go down the aspect path then you could catch these exceptions and display a certain page with ControllerAdvice, so in a way you could integrate exceptions there back to this view, although it's never really occurred to me to do this, but you might find this helpful, it's just you might be in a service within a service within a service and the parameters might not mean much to the user who made some initial request.

But in general it would be the simplest to do this validation in the controller if you can.

Comment: I'm developing rest api plus some communication will go through sockets, not MVC with views.. From my previous comment: 
"I put validation (also security) in service layer, science I have two interfaces which interacts with my application: REST and SOCKETS, and I don't want to duplicate validation and security code."

Comment: Anyway, I've implemented this with AOP.  In service layer, exception is thrown if any validation failed and rest controller handles it and passes ConstraintViolations from that exception back to api's consumer. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: No worries, you probably want your validation in your rest controller though ideally, but there may be cases where you want this in your service layer as your doing, good luck.